# JAVA Infinite Loop on Paint Component?

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop, paintcomponent

So, I have a program that records and shows the collision within a hash table. I've made it all record the collisions - what data collided, where it's supposed to be, and where it is in the table.

The problem is the paintcomponent seem to be stuck in an infinite loop. I can't figure out which part of the while loop.

I've tried removing the while loop but that gives me a compile-time error.
I've also tried putting a return within the if statement, but that only gives me 1 value out of x amount of crashes.

Here's my code:

```
     public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        int xpos = 20, ypos = 30;
        crash = 0;

        g.setFont(plainfont);

        g.drawString("Hash Crash count is: " + crash, xpos, ypos);
        while(hashtable != null){
            for (String name : names) {
                int start = hashtable.hashFunc3(name);      //locates where data must be
                int end = hashtable.locateCrash(name);      //locates where data is found
                if (start != end) {
                    ypos += 20;
                    crash++;
                    g.drawString("Hash Crash:", xpos, ypos);
                    g.drawString(name, 100, ypos);
                    g.drawString("should be at", 200, ypos);
                    g.drawString(Integer.toString(start), 300, ypos);
                    g.drawString("found at", 350, ypos);
                    g.drawString(Integer.toString(end), 400, ypos);
                    //return;
                }
            }
        }  
    }
```

Your help and input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What sets `hashtable` to a null value?

Comment: What class type is `hashtable` variable and when this condition going to be met `while(hashtable != null)` ? From the shown code it is practically next to impossible to say where the error is.

Comment: `if (hashtable != null)` instead of a `while`. Evidently the hashtable is made later.

Comment: @AndyTurner hashtable was created when a button is pushed. The table size is taken from the text field.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick response. But I found a fix to my stupid little problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no escape case where the `HashMap` is set to `null`. You need something like `if(start == end) hashtable = null;` to break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. Maybe not the best but...

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    int xpos = 20, ypos = 30;
    crash = 0;

    g.setFont(plainfont);

    g.drawString("Hash Crash count is: " + crash, xpos, ypos);
    while(hashtable != null){
        for (String name : names) {
            int start = hashtable.hashFunc3(name);      //locates where data must be
            int end = hashtable.locateCrash(name);      //locates where data is found
            if (start != end) {
                ypos += 20;
                crash++;
                g.drawString("Hash Crash:", xpos, ypos);
                g.drawString(name, 100, ypos);
                g.drawString("should be at", 200, ypos);
                g.drawString(Integer.toString(start), 300, ypos);
                g.drawString("found at", 350, ypos);
                g.drawString(Integer.toString(end), 400, ypos);
            }
        }
        break; //<-- needed a break; after for loop.
    }  
}
```

Comment: "needed a break; after for loop." Then you didn't need a loop. `if (hashtable != null)`.